# Enable Archives in attributes after creation (Woocommerce)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, archive

I know there is an checkbox to enable archives on attributes when you create them, but how to enable archives on attribute after creation. It would be insane that you need to remove all attributes and create new one because you haven't checked that one checkbox (Initially, 2 years ago, I did not needed archives and now I want them)

Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I found it - Make sure you click EDIT button on the term not the name!

[edit term image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxYwY.png)